# SQL Server query does not work with newest data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a table with ~54,000,000 rows. I have the following query:

```
SELECT  
    tap1.[id],
    tap1.[Mark],
    tap1.[Date_Write]
FROM
    [crpt].[dbo].[BI] tap1
JOIN 
    (SELECT mark 
     FROM [crpt].[dbo].[BI]     
     GROUP BY mark  
     HAVING COUNT(mark) = 2) t ON t.mark = tap1.mark 
WHERE
    date_write > '2023-09-26' 
    AND date_write < '2023-09-28'
ORDER BY
    date_write, mark
```

It resolves (and with other older dates) in 3 seconds, but if change the dates to newest ones like 2023-10-01/2023-10-03 it hangs and I don't get a result. What can be wrong here?

Comment: Blocking? Badly cached plan? Outdated statistics? There's a lot that could be going on. Can you [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for the query that isn't working? Are you using literals for both queries, rather than parameters?

Comment: I assumed by "hangs up" you meant "hangs". If you do mean "hangs up" (disconnects) then what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, it hangs for a 10-14 hours, and i am stopping it without result

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1vJwO7Sa

Comment: So you *are* using literals. It appears you don't have (m)any indexes on your table, which won't help the matter either. What indexes do you have on those tables? Can you add their definitions to the question? Does the query above result in a scan of both tables?

Comment: I would actually suggest an index on `Bottle_info(Mark, Date_Write)`. That index should support efficient execution of both the `GROUP BY mark HAVING COUNT(mark) = 2` for the `t` subquery and the subsequent seek by `mark` and `date_write` range for `tap1`. Other (*last resort*) suggestions if the above does not work are (1) Add a `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to eliminate parallelism. (2) Reverse the join placing the subquery first and *either* change it to an `INNER LOOP JOIN` *or* add `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` to the end of the query to coax the desired execution order.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the row count for the `SELECT mark FROM [crpt].[dbo].[BI] GROUP BY mark HAVING COUNT(mark) = 2` subquery? I'm hoping it is very much less than the total row count for BI.

Comment: answer for T N: GROUP BY mark HAVING COUNT(mark) = 2 is 0.5percent of all rows, i am using literals on sql management studio before i can put it in production

Comment: and why my studient question, and all of yor answers have -1 point, i understand, that my index rules or keys are not correct, and asks for help

Comment: The reason I was asking about the `COUNT(mark) = 2` row count is that the difference between this and the count of rows `WHERE date_write > '2023-09-26' AND date_write < '2023-09-28` may indicate which condition should be examined first for optimal execution plan: (1) Index scan and filter by count and then loop join and filter by date, (2) Index range seek by date and loop join and filter by count, or (3) lookup both and merge join. The SQL query optimizer tries to choose the best path based on statistics and available indexes, but sometimes it needs a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following indexes. You need both of these indexes to cover your query properly.

```sql
BI (Mark)
BI (Date_Write) INCLUDE (Mark, ID)
```

---

You can also try rewriting this query to use window functions, which should be substantially more efficient given the right indexes.

```sql
SELECT  
    tap1.id,
    tap1.Mark,
    tap1.Date_Write
FROM (
    SELECT
      tap1.*,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Mark) AS countPerMark
    FROM dbo.BI tap1
) tap1
WHERE
    tap1.Date_Write > '2023-09-26' 
    AND tap1.Date_Write < '2023-09-28'
    AND tap1.countPerMark = 2
ORDER BY
    date_write, mark;
```

You probably want the following index for this

```sql
BI (Mark) INCLUDE (Date_Write, ID)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have the necessary indexes, it might be probably due to cached plan. Try executing it with a recompile (and I think in real code you are using variables rather then constants for parameters):

```
SELECT  tap1.[id]
  ,tap1.[Mark]      
  ,tap1.[Date_Write]
FROM [crpt].[dbo].[BI] tap1
JOIN (select mark from [crpt].[dbo].[BI]        
    group by mark       
    having count(mark)=2 ) t on t.mark=tap1.mark 

    where date_write> '20231001' and date_write< '20231003'
ORDER by date_write,mark
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```